# Why does this MVC async action fail?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, async-await

I am trying to make use of async controller actions, to follow the pattern of the typical Identity `AccountController` code, but I get the following error if I access the page directly (and silently hangs if I go via a redirect after login):

```
The specified parameter type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not valid. Only scalar types, such as System.Int32, System.Decimal, System.DateTime, and System.Guid, are supported.
Parameter name: item 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The specified parameter type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not valid. Only scalar types, such as System.Int32, System.Decimal, System.DateTime, and System.Guid, are supported.
Parameter name: item

Source Error: 

Line 107:        public async Task<Candidate> CurrentCandidate()
Line 108:        {
Line 109:            return await this.Context.Candidate.FindAsync(this.CurrentCandidateId());
Line 110:        }
Line 111:
```

### The controller action (does nothing with the user yet):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int id = 0)
{
    // Get current user
    var candidate = await base.CurrentCandidate();

    if (candidate != null)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(candidate.CandidateGuid.ToString());
    }
    return View();
}
```

### and the base helper method it calls is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Return the current logged-in candidate, based on the current candidate id
/// </summary>
public async Task<Candidate> CurrentCandidate()
{
    return await this.Context.Candidate.FindAsync(this.CurrentCandidateId());
}
```

where Context is a typical EF6 database context.

### the last helper method involved is:

```
public async Task<int> CurrentCandidateId()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user != null)
        {
            return user.CandidateId.GetValueOrDefault(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What am I overlooking? I am new to this new style of async coding, so feel free to educate me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `CurrentCandidateId` function is `async` and returns a `Task<int>`. `DbSet.FindAsync` takes any kind of objects, but it *definitely* doesn't know what to do with a `Task<int>`. You instead need to `await` on that task and get its result to pass to `FindAsync`.

```
public async Task<Candidate> CurrentCandidate()
{
    return await this.Context.Candidate
        .FindAsync(await this.CurrentCandidateId());
    //             ^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Just spotted that missing `await` at the same time you answered. Well done. :) I guess that is because `FindAsync` takes `object[]` as a parameter, so the compiler did not warn :)